# Android listview changes color if adapter not created onCreate()

Tags: android, listview

ListView has a weird behavior when I create adapter after loading data from a server than when I create the adapter in onCreate function.
Color of the text in list turns white if the list is created onNext() function instead of the onCreate().
Any ideas what that could be?

```
public class PdfListActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
private StableArrayAdapter adapter;
private PdfModelView modelView;
private ListView listview;
private Context instanceVar;
private ArrayList<PdfRetrive> dataObj;

@Bind(R.id.toolbar)
Toolbar toolbar;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_pdf_list);

listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listviewdoc);

instanceVar = getApplicationContext();

modelView = new PdfModelView();
modelView.getPdf().subscribe(pdfSubscriber);

listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view,
                            int position, long id) {
        final String item = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

        ArrayList<VOS.PdfObject> pdfArr = (ArrayList<VOS.PdfObject>)      dataObj.get(position).pdfs;

        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> urlArr = new ArrayList<String>();
        int total = pdfArr.size();

        for (int i = 0; i < total; ++i) {
            list.add(pdfArr.get(i).title);
            urlArr.add(pdfArr.get(i).url);
        }

        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PdfSecondListActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("pdf", list);
        i.putExtra("url", urlArr);
        startActivity(i);
    }

});

}
private Subscriber pdfSubscriber = new     Subscriber<VOS.BackEndResponseObject<ArrayList<PdfRetrive>>>() {
@Override
public void onCompleted()
{
}

@Override
public void onError(Throwable e)
{
    Log.d("pdfs", "recived");
}

@Override
public void onNext(VOS.BackEndResponseObject<ArrayList<PdfRetrive>> arrayListBackEndResponseObject)
{
    dataObj = arrayListBackEndResponseObject.data;
    final ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    int total = arrayListBackEndResponseObject.data.size();

    for (int i = 0; i < total; ++i) {
        list.add(arrayListBackEndResponseObject.data.get(i).name);
    }

    adapter  = new StableArrayAdapter(instanceVar, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);
}
};
```

Comment: Post the cod generating the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems it was a problem of how I initialized the adapter:
I should have gone with:

```
adapter = new StableArrayAdapter(PdfListActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
```

This solved my problem.